# Check condition before extracting files inno

Tags: inno-setup

I want to check if there is a certain file before starting to extract, because if there is that file installation must stop. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean a file from the setup archive (conditionally added to the setup archive e.g.), or an external file (stored somewhere on disk) ? And when do you want to do that check (before the wizard is shown, before the installation starts, or...) ?

Comment: Before the instalaation starts, but I just found a way, I am going to post it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a way; I've used the `CurStepChanged` event method and wait there for `CurStep=ssInstall` which indicates the installation process is about to start. At that time I check if the file exists, and if so, I terminate the setup process:

```
[Code]
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: UINT);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\.versionC204v1')) then
    begin
      MsgBox('A patched version detected. Setup will now exit.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      ExitProcess(0);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You might consider returning an exit code different from 0, as Inno Setup (as many other programs) uses exit code 0 to indicate success.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thank you. And thank you again for editing the code.